# Transparent switch from single fileserver to DFS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs

Currently we're maintaining an environment with a single Windows Server 2008 R2 fileserver. We'd like to replace the server with a Server 2012 R2 machine and switch to DFS (fileshare on dfs server, without replication).

Now I have the problem that the old server could have been referenced by:

- \\IP\sharename
- \\hostname\sharename
- \\FQND\sharename

And I don't know what links the users have in their documents. When I now switch to the new server with dfs, the old hostname becomes invalid anyway and I can only reference the new share by:

- \\hostname\sharename (which would be without DFS and therefore wrong and, of course, the new host has a new name anyway) or:
- \\domain\namespace\share

Long story short: Is there a possibility to switch to DFS but keeping the old paths still valid (some sort of alias or something)?

Answer (score -1):

Okay, as it doesn't seem like somebody here has an answer, I'm going to post what I've found out (if somebody has a better way to do it, please feel free to post it;))

First, it seems like my statement from above is true: a new DFS-Namespace can't be compatible with an old fileshare which has been accessed by its UNC-Path. For some situation there is a feature which may help in some situations, called 'DFS Consolidation Roots'. Be aware though, that this solution only works with standalone namespaces and not AD integrated (AFAIK).

For me, I chose the following solution:

1. Robocopy all the files to the new server
2. Create the shares on the new server with the same relative UNC-Path (what I mean is: \hostname\"everything after hostname stays the same")
3. Robocopy a second time (diff only)
4. Remove old server from AD-Domain (very important for later steps ;))
5. Shutdown old server
6. Add a CNAME-Record to the DNS, pointing from the old hostname to the new one
7. Configure DFS
8. Configure all applications under my controll to use the DFS-Path from now on

Be aware though, that you need to configure the new server that it accepts requests initiated to this alternate name (got it from here: http://md3v.com/enable-windows-server-smb-2-0-alias-cname):

1. regedit: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
2. REG_DWORD 32bit: DisableStrictNameChecking, Value : 1
3. reboot your server.
4. setspn -a host/"oldname" "hostname of new server"
5. setspn -a host/"oldFQND" "hostname of new server"

I didn't rollout it in production yet, but in the lab it worked decently. In my opinion, it's a good way to rollout DFS without breaking all document templates or user-built scripts you aren't even aware of.

But: Next time I'm setting up a fileserver for a new customer, I'm totally going to use DFS from the beginning ;)

Kind regards, Christian

Comment: You're introducing a security risk with this method, not to mention you're not fixing the issue just delaying when you have to fix it. If I were you, I'd install DFS-R on the old server, install the new one, replicate the content, and migrate people to the proper DFS share. Then work out what broken things need to be fixed and decommission the old server completely. Keeping legacy shunts in place is going to bite you in the ass in a year.